# Lost question text when creating an account before posting

Tags: bug

I am unable to type quickly. I spent about 20 minutes trying to type a clear and specific question about a Linux related question. After completing the question I was asked to create an account: login via Google, login via Facebook. I chose Facebook. For some reason the login failed. When I tried to return to the question that I had typed, everything I had typed was gone. I was left with the option to retype everything or give up and move on. It would have been nice to have had the ability to return to what I had already typed.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @kemotep this isn't really a question as much as a bug report. What Jeff is describing is obviously not a pleasant experience and SE should make sure your question isn't lost if it forces you to create an account.

Comment: Hmm. Question and answer fields used to save what you typed; I wonder if that doesn't exist anymore or doesn't work for people who aren't logged in yet

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66238/307535 says that "Drafts work for anonymous users as well"

Comment: It's too late to be helpful for this situation, but for semi-complex answers that might take a while to finish, I find myself saving them elsewhere before posting to Stack Exchange; that way, I don't have to rely on the saved draft (and could harmlessly post a shorter answer in the interim).

Comment: @terdon I wondered if they would edit it back into their original lost question, hence my comment. However I think migrating it here to meta was a good call. When logged in on multiple devices I can see drafts for earlier posts I have not submitted. I wonder when you are logged in versus being anonymous how your session cookies may be changed or over written.

Comment: If the server stored what was entered my non-logged-in-users, then it would be vulnerable to Denial Of Service attack. However maybe it should have got you to login, before asking you to type the question.

Comment: They are presumably saved as cookies. I know I can start typing a question, then close the browser and the question will appear as soon as I click on the "Ask question" button after opening the browser again.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor that wouldn't be an issue if the question is stored as a local cookie, right?

Comment: @terdon yes I agree, local cookie will not use any server memory.